# How to test Callback of Material Pagination Element in Functional Component?

Tags: reactjs, testing, material-ui

I'm  trying to get full unit test coverage using `'@testing-library/react'` but am having trouble triggering the callbacks of Material's [React Pagination Component](https://material-ui.com/components/pagination/). When I simulate a click on the next page button, I still see no coverage of the callback defined in my file. Nor can I replace this callback with a mocked callback because it is defined inside my functional component, so a mocked one cannot be passed in as a parameter. Here's what I've tried so far. Any help is really appreciated.

DataMonitoring.tsx

```
const DataMonitoring: React.FC<DataMonitoringProps> = ({}: DataMonitoringProps) => {

  const handleChangePage = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement> | null, newPageIndex: number) => {
    console.log("it works"); // not begin logged on simulated click
  };

  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    console.log("it works"); // not being logged on simulated click
  };

  return (
        <TablePagination
          rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 20, 50]}
          component="div"
          count={10}
          page={0}
          onPageChange={handleChangePage}
          rowsPerPage={4}
          onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        />
  );
};
```

DataMonitoring.test.tsx

```
describe('DataMonitoring Pagination Test', () => {
  it('handles page onchange', () => {
    const mockPageIndex = 0;
    const mockPageSize = 0;
    const mockTotalObjects = 0;
    const { container } = render(
      <DataMonitoring/>
    );
    const nextPageBtn = container.querySelector('[title="Next page"]');
    userEvent.click(nextPageBtn);   
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Let us say your pagination component is like this

```
import TablePagination from '@mui/material/TablePagination'
function ComponentUnderTest({page, rpp, setPage, setRowsPerPage}){
   return <TablePagination
      component="div"
      count={total}
      page={page}
      onPageChange={(_, newPage) => {
        setPage(newPage)
      }}
      rowsPerPage={rpp}
      onRowsPerPageChange={(event) => {
        setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10))
      }}
    />
  }
```

You can mock the pagination component like this.

```
const tablePagination = {}
const TablePagination = (props) => {
      tablePagination.props = props
      return <div>table pagination</div>
}
jest.mock('@mui/material/TablePagination', () => TablePagination)
```

Then in your test, check the callback functions like this

```
tablePagination.props.onPageChange(null, 2)
expect(mockSetPage).toHaveBeenCalledWith(2)
```

Leave triggering of the onPageChange and onRowsPerPageChange on button click to the mui. We need to test what we do when the callback is triggered.